# Learning videos for electronic concepts?

Tags: video

Are there any interesting and graphical videos for learning electronic concepts, like basic principles of capacitor, inductor, resistor, transistor and other advanced concepts like digital electronics?

I am mostly looking for animated videos which would teach me concepts and possibly their practical applications. I have been reading books but haven't made much progress.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I really like this interactive circuit simulator.

http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-index.html

Comment: Nice one and very interesting!!

Comment: I have and always will love watching these simulations.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you're looking for, but after you get beyond the introductions that Joby pointed out and on to the practical applications part, you'll want to get comfortable with a simulator so you can try out your own designs and change some of the numbers around.  Most of the web videos don't let you play with the circuits more than flipping switches, and breadboarding all your circuits takes a long time.

Linear Technology's LTspice is an introductory SPICE simulation environment :( for Windows only) which has an easy learning curve and includes a huge number of switching regulator demo circuits (which are one of many applications for caps, inductors, and transistors).  There's a simple video introduction [here](http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/Videos/), an active support group [here](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/LTspice/), and the manual is [here](http://ltspice.linear.com/software/scad3.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

These are for the most part higher level then what you are asking for.

There is a professor I know whom has put many [videos on youtube to teach about a range of concepts](http://www.youtube.com/user/kridnix).

Some are about changing education, some are about engineering design, and some are about optics related concepts. Now, none of these may interest you, but he does one of the better explanations of a [Fourier](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObklYbQaX24) [transform](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO3kgwYzpZg). Fourier links to the first, transform links to the second part, in case you have a hard time finding it.

This professor is big on trying to make engineering education more available to students, and feels with good teaching almost anyone can learn the basics of very complicated subjects, as you see he does some basic maxwell's equations(very basic) and teaching many concepts related to his lasers class. Students build a working laser with a gain medium and mirror by the end of it.

Comment: Good link, however most of the videos on the are highly technical and I could understand the LED and Photodiode out of those, I will seal it up for future use though..

Comment: Yes, you should be able to understand his discussion of education in the 21st century. You might gain some value from his functional decomposition lectures if you would like to know more about how to approach breaking down a problem.

Comment: He does teach optics and Lasers though.  I think that If I got you the order to watch the videos in, you could learn them without a problem, but out of order you will be missing concepts.